# How to remove files or packages from setuptools?

Tags: python, build, publish, release, setuptools

I cannot remove python modules/packages using `setuptools`

Here is the `setup.py`

```
setup(
    name = "ProjName",
    version = "0.1.0",
    author = "Boss",
    author_email = "boss@company.com",
    packages = find_packages(),
)
```

Here is my directory struct:

```
C:.
├───build
│   └...
├───dist
│   └...
├───foo1
│   └───bar1.py
└───setup.py
```

I can run the following command with no error and **with expected result** (the generated `egg` contains the `foo` package and the `bar` module) `setup.py bdist_egg`

**BUT** if I **remove** (or just rename) the `bar1.py` or the `foo1` directory the previous command (`setup.py bdist_egg`) generates an egg (no error/warning), which **generated egg still contains** (also) the `foo1` package or the `bar1.py` file.

Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: running `setup.py clean --all bdist_egg` can solve the main issue, but I don`t know how/why setuptools can remember missing files.

Comment: `setuptools` caches the files left from previous build in the `build/` directory; this comes handy when you have some heavy files requiring long time to be compiled. However, when you rename or remove a source file, `setuptools` is not smart enough to clean up the correspondent file in the `build/` dir, so you have to either remove the build dir or use the `python setup.py clean` command.